# i get error with : getResourceHelper in Abstract.php

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.6

i have an error magento when im trying to upgrade from 1.4x to 1.6x, i did it in localhost, i copied the folder skin, media, app from my old magento in server to new magento in localhost, n dump the sql, this is the error..

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::getResourceHelper() in C:\Ampps\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\Abstract.php on line 533

help guys!?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you copied the app folder - did you copy app/code too? If so, I'm willing to bet that's where your problem lies.

You've just copied all the 1.4 code over the top of the 1.6 stuff, so there is bound to be errors.

You should copy over:

- /skin/
- /app/design/
- /app/etc/local.xml
- /app/etc/modules/
- /media/
- /app/code/local/ (if you have anything in here)
- /app/code/community/ (if you have installed any 3rd party modules)

When copying files, I suggest you do NOT overwrite existing files. As long as your theme is set up correctly (for example, you haven't just edited a built-in theme), and your code was written in the proper way (copying core files into local, or writing your own extensions), this should be fine.

If you do have any local code, you can expect to have to fiddle with it to get it working on the newer version of Magento. There were quite a few changes between 1.4 and 1.6 (and then again for 1.7, which I'd recommend you upgrade to).

The database structure may also have changed between those versions (I can't confirm that) so I'd also be wary that just bumping and importing the MySQL database could cause you problems (it might work, but it might not!).